# Visual Studio Code: How to change color of modified repository?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with over 30 to 40 repositories and submodules in a visual studio code. All this repositories are shown as source control. I want to highlight modified repositories in source control by changing their colors. Right now i could not find any option to change colors of modified repositories. How to change the colors of this repositories in source control.

Changed repositories right now show a simple asterick (*) mark near branch name. How to change its  color for better highlighting.

[image]

Comment: Currently I don't  think there is anything out-of-the box. I believe extensions have access to the source control view though. If they do, you can probably read the source code to find the hook that the astrik uses to add highlighting, if you have time to create such an extension. If you have the time, but the hook isn't accessible, or the view isn't accessible by extensions, you can create your own vscode patch that adds it. Thats the best I got for you. Lastly, this option can take some time, but you should make a request to add the feature on the VSCode GitHub Issues page.

Comment: Opened feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128618

Comment: too bad i missed the vote...